# Program in c stop no reason

Tags: c

Hello this is my function please help me to know what the problem is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LENGTH 10

void searchingFunc(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber);
void placesOfNum(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber);
int evenPlaces(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber);

int main()
{
    int len =10,someNum =0,i=0,ans=0;
    int someArr[LENGTH]={0};
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        printf("enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d",&someArr[i]);
    }
    printf("now, enter the other number\n");
    scanf("%d",&someNum);
    searchingFunc(someArr,len,someNum);
    placesOfNum(someArr,len,someNum);
    ans = evenPlaces(someArr,len,someNum);
    printf("%d",ans);
    return 0;
}

/**
this function
input:
output:
*/
void searchingFunc(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < number) && (specialNumber != arr[i])) 
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (i < number)
    {
        printf("the number found\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
      printf("the Number not found\n");
    }
}

/**
this function
input:
output:
*/
void placesOfNum(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        if (specialNumber== arr[i])
        {
            printf("in the %d\n",i+1);
        }
    }

}


/**
this function
input:
output:
*/
int evenPlaces(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber)
{
    int i=1,sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<=number;i+2) //because the counting start from 0
    {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    return sum;

}
```

the function work but at the end, it stopping work, and doesn't print the last number - the sum of the even numbers. please help me thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include only the problematic part of the code. See how to write a [mcve]. Also include sample output.

Comment: Try replacing `printf("%d",ans);` with `printf("%d\n",ans);`.

Comment: Which function works (I can see at least 3) and how do you know?

Comment: the first and the second is work, but the third isn't @doctorlove

Comment: still not work @Badministrator

Comment: You have a Statement with no effect here: `for(i=1;i<=number;i+2)` change it to `for(i=1;i<number;i+=2)` and also inside `int specialNumber` arg from `int evenPlaces(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber)` there is no use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `evenPlaces` function, you are not updating `i` in `for` loop. You also have to change `i<=number` to `i < number`.

Change

```
for(i=1;i<=number;i+2)
```

to

```
for(i = 1; i < number; i = i+2) {}
```

[<kbd>Working Code</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WGLak6)

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com]) should be used only to show a code but not as DEMO of a working one as you say. there is no use of `int specialNumber` inside `int evenPlaces(int arr[],int number,int specialNumber)` but ideone doesn't check that.  Inside main there is a call of it `ans = evenPlaces(someArr,len,someNum);`

Comment: @Michi; Will it solve the problem by just removing this parameter from `evenPlaces`? I  just addressed the reason why program is not working.

Comment: there is a call of it inside`main` which means that it should be used inside that function, not removed. Any way my point was about [Ideone](http://ideone.com) and not about the code. The OP's function is wrong too . I never said that your Answer doesn't help OP's problem :)